# How to make a HTTP Request in MaxMsp?

Tags: httprequest, multipartform-data, max-msp-jitter

Here I am facing a problem with `MaxMsp`. I want to send a sound file (no longer than 5 secs) to a web API, and get data from it.

This is how it works: I record or send a wav file (no longer than 5 secs), and get an analyzation back, which has the data (number, max 50) of my emotions like my anger, joy, calmness, energy.

Now I want to use MaxMsp to do this http request.
There are two links may be needed

1. [THE SPECIFICATION OF THIS WEBAPI](http://file:///Users/SJY/Downloads/Empath%20WebAPI%20Specification%20-%20v1%20(1).pdf)
2. [MAXMSP REFERENCE OF "MAXURL"](https://docs.cycling74.com/max7/maxobject/maxurl)

And my max file and a sample of a short screaming wav are in [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-G-wouEq0hAdU8xYm9zRW16YXc?usp=sharing)

I'd be very appreciate if you could help. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

In order to send multipart-form request, you need to use `dictionary` message.

And there are some detail which didn't write in the document of [maxurl](https://docs.cycling74.com/max7/maxobject/maxurl),

The answer is the **order of type** of request,

If you use `filename_in`, `post_data` and `multipart_form`, then there still only one of them will be sent. In this case, the `filename_in` has the highest priority, second is `post_data`, the `multipart_form` is the last.

**So, if you are using `multipart_form`, be sure you're not using others at the same time.**